# Ansible tries to connect to VM IP before executing the role creating the VM

Tags: ansible, vmware, orchestration

I'm trying to develop an Ansible script to generate a VM. I wrote a `myvm` role that contains the script that orchestrates `vmware_guest`. This script contains a `delegate_to: localhost` which `vmware_guest` requires.

Then, I added my new-to-be-vm to hosts, and added the following to `hosts`:

```
[myvms]
myvm1
```

and extended `site.yml` with:

```
- hosts: myvms
  roles: 
    - myvm
```

Now, when I run:

`ansible-playbook site.yml -i hosts --limit myvm1`

it fails with:

> fatal: [myvm1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Connection reset by 192.168.10.13 port 22\r\n", "unreachable": true}

It seems ansible tries to connect to the vm ip before reading the actual role that creates the vm where it delegates to localhost. Adding 'delegate_to' to site.yml fails, however.

How can I fix my Ansible scripts to properly generate the VM for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `gather_facts: false` to the play.

```
- hosts: myvms
  gather_facts: false
  roles: 
    - myvm
```

Ansible by default connects to target machines and runs script which collect data (facts).

Comment: But the vm is created inside the role. wait_for will wait until the vm is available. But unless the role is executed, it will _never_ be available.